# Is Core Data Migration necessary if I change the type of an attribute in the model from NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, core-data, model, attributes, migration

We have an app in the App Store, and I want to change the type of an attribute in the model from an NSString to an NSDate. Since Core Data migration only modifies the persistent store (in my case an SQLite database), would I need to do core data migration since only the data type in the model changes. By the way, our database is prepopulated, and we will never have to modify the value for that attribute in the database

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bit late but I solved it with this!

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/197476-custom-entity-migration-policies-atribute-from-nsstring-to-nsdate.html